# ffmpeg get 403 forbidden but the m3u8 link working fine at any other player as Kodi, VLC/desktop and apple tv

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, capture

Gus, I got this puzzle going on. There is a m3u8 playlist with mutiple streams that works fine at any platform like kodi, vlc etc. I try to capture the lower resolution video stream as a record. Buy my command alway got error notice like:

```
Failed to set value '0:v:1' for option 'map': Option not found
```

By using `ffmpeg -i` "resource" I can get the streams map like following:

```
  Program 0
Metadata:
  variant_bitrate : 488000
Stream #0:0: Data: timed_id3 (ID3  / 0x20334449)
Metadata:
  variant_bitrate : 488000
Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p, 426x240 [SAR 1:1 DAR 71:40], 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc
Metadata:
  variant_bitrate : 488000
Stream #0:2: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
Metadata:
  variant_bitrate : 488000 .........
```

I have tried the command following:

```
ffmpeg -i "video_source_playlist..." -map 0:v:1 -map 0:a:2 -c copy output.ts
```

And every time I am told that the value `0:v:1` is not the option for `map`:

```
option not found
```

Someone can teach me how to set the right parameters of -map that I can make it work?
With many thanks!

Comment: Q title does not match Q body. Run your command with -report added and share report file.

Comment: thank you so much @Gyan !!
The report is very long, I am supposed it can't be pasted here at one piece.

Comment: Please try this lin to my report: https://autoclave210290568.files.wordpress.com/2019/01/ffmpeg-report.pdf

Comment: Run the failing command with -report !